# Creating Android widgets using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-widget

Is it possible to create android homescreen widgets using phonegap ?

Comment: It's been a while since the original post.  Does anyone know if this has changed?

Answer (score 4):

It's defiantly possible. 
But yes you will need to be writing native code and have an understanding of Java/Android.

And any updating the widget needs to do, refreshing from a web service, will need to be written in Java/Android. As you can not talk to the javascript from the Service required to update the widget.

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/installing-app-as-a-widget-on-the-home-screen-of-android/10616
copy/pasted answers, why not cite the original?

Answer (score 3):

According to [various posts](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=+site%3agroups.google.com+phonegap+android+widgets&pbx=1&oq=+site%3agroups.google.com+phonegap+android+widgets&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=621l621l0l2910l1l1l0l0l0l0l71l71l1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=918a461f06fdbea1&biw=1280&bih=702) on the PhoneGap's Google Group it doesn't seem to be possible, at least not without heavily modifying the core.