# Weather widget for phonegap

Tags: cordova, widget

I need to implement a phonegap application with info from my town. Something they ask me to provide is a page with the weather for the day.

I have looked for weather widgets to be used in phonegap with no luck (actually as I am a total newbie in phonegap development I don't even know whether it is possible to use widgets in this kind of app).

Anybody would give me a hand on this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to read:

[Creating Android widgets using phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755318/creating-android-widgets-using-phonegap)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/U5gr-rz2anQ

But to be honest i dont think you can do that right now, atleast not without writing some Java.  :)

I hope my answer helped you atleast a bit :)